# Django Admin model create new instance instead of update

Tags: python, django

I've multiple models in my Django project but only this given below model creating another instance on update instead of save. This is happening in Django's Admin panel, not on my custom UI. When I remove my `save()` method then it works fine but this way I won't be able to create `slug`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong in here

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='category')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, primary_key=True, auto_created=False)
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    requirements = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(9.99)])
    level = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    application_link = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    brochure = models.FileField(upload_to='brochures/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/')
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_session_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    session_url = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If you alter the slug, and that is the primary key, that is indeed what will happen.

Comment: So what should I do ? I mean how should I handle my slug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of overriding save method you could do this:

admin.py

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because it will generate new slug every time. You can do something like this:

```py
    def generate_slug(self):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.generate_slug() # This will generate slug.

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```